# How to check containsKey in Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I want to check if below mentioned dictionary contains a particular key or not.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>
```

Comment: wow. which dictionary's key?

Comment: I want to check at all three labels....

Comment: What is the problem you're having? `.ContainsKey` is not a difficult method to call... Even if you want to check the inner dictionaries, that's just a `foreach` over the children. It doesn't look like you've tried anything yourself.

Comment: Consider re-designing your data strcuctre

Comment: you cannot efficiently check the innermost dictionaries.

Comment: I know how to call .ContainsKey but not sure how to call at all dictionaries...

Comment: I need something like..... Dictionary_first.ContainsKey(someValue).Dictionary_second.ContainsKey(someValue).Dictionary_third.ContainsKey(someValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check with 3 keys one for outer dict and one for inner dict.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> dict= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(); 
 if (dict.ContainsKey(outerKey))
 {
   var innerDict = dict[outerKey];
   if (innerDict.ContainsKey(innerKey))
   {  
       var innerMost = innerDict[innerKey];
       if (innerMost.ContainsKey(innerMostKey))
        var item = innerMost[innerMostKey]; // This is the item of inner most dict
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to check one by one, I guess like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> dictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("someKey"))
{
    var secondDictionary = dictionary["someKey"];
    if (secondDictionary.ContainsKey("otherKey"))
    {
        var thirdDictionary = secondDictionary["otherKey"];
        if (thirdDictionary.ContainsKey("thirdKey"))
        {
            var final = thirdDictionary["thirdKey"];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @user1667760, I am not sure if a data structure like this would be helpful to you, I am hoping you are just trying to test some code, because otherwise this data structure could lead you to complexity and *may be* lack in performance

Comment: Instead of using ContainsKey and then doing in an indexer lookup, you should do a TryGetValue; otherwise, the indexer ends up calling ContainsKey again internally. If you're calling a dictionary many times, especially recursively, it can give a huge performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a nested foreach loop if you for the outer two dictionaries to make that work.

Something like

```
        var nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
        var foundCounter = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> midLevel in nestedDictionary)
        {
            var key = midLevel.Key;
            if (key.Equals("WHATAMILOOKINGFOR"))
            {
                foundCounter++;
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> lowerLevel in midLevel.Value)
            {
                if (key.Equals("WHATAMILOOKINGFOR"))
                {
                    foundCounter++;
                }
                if(lowerLevel.Value.ContainsKey("WHATAMILOOKINGFOR"))
                {
                    foundCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

I didn't use var on the foreach so you could explicitly see the types.